# Change input property by clicking on a label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I need:

If I click on a label I want to add a checked in the input.

When I try it I got two alerts with a true. That isn't correct and in firebug the input field doesn't change.

For a test I want to output the filterguid but the alerts are empty and again there are two alert boxes.

HTML Markup:

```
<li>
 <label>
  <input type="checkbox" filterguid="895f7bc2-d609-4b09-97f9-c09f9fc90d1b"> Weiblich
  </label>
</li>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.targetgroup-frame li label').on('click', function(){
   $(this).children().prop('checked', true);
    alert($(this).children().prop('filterguid'));
});
```

Is my jQuery code correct?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't need any JS for this - it's default HTML behaviour. I'm confused as to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Why is the label not doing this already? That is how a label works when you attach it properly to a checkbox. And by looking at your code it should be doing that. Now if you do not want them to be able to uncheck it by clicking on the label (which seems weird) than yes you would need some code and it would require some logic with the checkbox.

Comment: `$(this).children().prop('checked', true);` this doesn't need to be there and **filterguid** is an attribute not a property.

Comment: ^ you need to add attribute `for` to label which will have id of checkbox

Comment: @llamerr not in this case as the `input` is the child of the `label`.

Comment: @llamerr: no, you don't: not if the `<input>` is inside of the `<label>`; the `for` attribute simply associates an `<input>` and `<label>`, which is alreay accomplished by having the `<input>` inside of the `<label>`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you right, didn't knew (or forgot) about that

Comment: But why in the firebug the dom of the input doesn't change if I click on the label? I use the code to change style of the label if the input is checked.

Comment: It is better to add the event click to the input checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML - no changes except adding a id on the input for easy jquery-targeting.

```
<li>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" filterguid="895f7bc2-d609-4b09-97f9-c09f9fc90d1b"> Weiblich
    </label>
</li>
```

You don't have to use jquery to change the state of the checkbox since html does that for you.

You can listen for the changes and get the checked state and filterguid with the following script.

```
$('#checkbox').change(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('filterguid'))
    console.log(this.checked)
});
```

Comment: How about explaining what you changed, and why, and then explain why the alert happened multiple times.

Comment: Thank you. With that code I can check if the input field is checked and change the style of the label.

Comment: @cgee: Just so you know, the `.prop()` method was replaced by `.attr()` because there are only certain attributes that automatically get mapped to object properties. Custom attributes do not. If you had used a `data-` attribute, you could've used `this.dataset.filterguid` in modern browsers to get the data. The multiple alerts happened because when a `label` triggers a behavior on its related input control, it causes a `click` event to occur, so there was the user's actual click, and then the additional label-induced click.

Answer (score -2):

#### Label for attribute

> The ID of a labelable form-related element in the same document as the label element. The first such element in the document with an ID matching the value of the for attribute is the labeled control for this label element.

Also, you should `data-attribute` instead of `attribute`. `attribute` is not supported by HTM5

#### Sample

```js
$("#chkTest").on("click", function(){
  console.log($(this).data("filterguid"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="chkTest">
  <input id="chkTest" type="checkbox" data-filterguid="895f7bc2-d609-4b09-97f9-c09f9fc90d1b">Weiblich
</label>
```

#### References

- [Label - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label).

Comment: @Downvoter, Please find updated answer. Hope this adds what was missing.

Comment: Guys Please comment if something is missing. Everyone here has come to learn and I would like to fill this gap in my understanding.